# C# Array with DateTime[]

Tags: c#, arrays, datetime

How can I turn multiple If statements into a single array to check file datetime of several files with the same name?

Currently I have

```
if (location1)
{
    loc = 1;
    DateTime dateDailyFile1 = Convert.ToDateTime(File.GetLastWriteTime(ediFile1));
    if (Convert.ToDateTime(dateDailyFile1.ToShortDateString()) < Convert.ToDateTime(DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString()))
    {
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        return true;
    }
}...
```

I do this about 20 times.  Which as you may gather is quite grueling.
I wanted to put it in an array and just loop through it but the DateTime assignment on the array keeps throwing an error.
The following is the code I'm trying to change it to.
**qualifier - location[] is a bool assigned by clicking a checkbox.

```
DateTime[] dateDailyFile;
string[] ediFile = { "file1", "file2", "file3", "file4" ... };
string[] loc = { "loc1", "loc2", "loc3", "loc4" ... };
int x;
for (x = 0; x < loc.length; x++)
{
    if (location[x])
        {
            dateDailyFile[x] = Convert.ToDateTime(File.GetLastWriteTime(ediFile[x]));
        }
}...
```

The last line 
dateDailyFile[x] = Convert.ToDateTime(File.GetLastWriteTime(ediFile[x]));
is my problem.  I am getting a "Use of unassigned local variable dateDailyFile".

What exactly did I do wrong and what is the best method to solve this issue?

Comment: What are `ediFile1` and `location1` in your first example?  It looks like you're trying to access variables `x1`, `x2`, `x3`, etc. as if they're an array which is not possible with the syntax you're using.

Comment: Do you have a specific format of datetime in this file?

Comment: `File.GetLastWriteTime` already returns a `DateTime`, so why are you using `Convert.ToDateTime`?

Comment: arrays need to have a size specified.

Comment: `dateDailyFile` is declared but not initialized.  That's why you get your current error.  Use your debugger.  Look at its value, you'll see it's null.

Comment: Also instead of `Convert.ToDateTime(someDate.ToShortDateString())` just use `someDate.Date`, it will zero out the time portion and let you just compare the date portion.

Comment: What should be put into `dateDailyFile[x]` when `location[x]` returns `false`?

Comment: Dmitry, when location[x] returns false dateDailyFile[x] is never used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It *seems* like you are trying to access variables by their string name, which is not possible with that syntax.  However, you *could* store the *values* in an array like so:

```
var ediFile = new []{ file1, file2, file3, file4 ... };
var loc = new [] { loc1, loc2, loc3, loc4 ... };
```

Then access then using array indexers:

```
int x;
for (x = 0; x < loc.length; x++)
{
    if (location[x])
        {
            dateDailyFile[x] = Convert.ToDateTime(File.GetLastWriteTime(ediFile[x]));
        }
}...
```

Comment: It was a combination that helped me work out the correct process. D.Stanley's explanation of my error along with ispiro's correction helped me work out the correct process - listed below.

Answer (score 4):

Change the first line to:

```
DateTime[] dateDailyFile = new DateTime[whateverIsTheExpectedLength];//20?
```

Answer (score 2):

Arrays need a length defined at declaration.

You can instead use a `List`, which doesn't need a size specified at declaration, making it more flexible:

```
List<DateTime> dateDailyFile;
string[] ediFile = { "file1", "file2", "file3", "file4" ... };
string[] loc = { "loc1", "loc2", "loc3", "loc4" ... };
int x;
for (x = 0; x < loc.length; x++)
{
    if (location[x])
        {
            dateDailyFile.Add(Convert.ToDateTime(File.GetLastWriteTime(ediFile[x])));
        }
}...
```

Answer (score 0):

It was a combination that helped me work out the correct process. D.Stanley's explanation of my error along with ispiro's correction helped me work out the correct process - listed below.

```
var ediFile = new[] {loc1, loc2, loc3, loc4 ...}
DateTime[] dateDailyFile = new DateTime[20]; 
int x;
        for (x = 0; x < bLocation.Length; x++)
        {
            if (bLocation[x])
            {
                ....
                dateDailyFile[x] = Convert.ToDateTime(File.GetLastWriteTime(ediFile[x]));
                return false;
            }
            else
            {
                return true;
            }
        }...
```

D. Stanley correctly identified the root cause coupled with ispiro's suggestion I managed to get it working.

String[] loc was not needed in the correction.